# Question regarding $C^*$ algebra generated by a product

Tags: functional-analysis, c-star-algebras

Let $V=M_{1,\infty}$,the row Hilbert space. Suppose $W$ denotes the $C^*-$ algebra generated by $V^*V=\{x^*y : x,y \in V \}$

> Is it true that $W= K(l_2)$, space of compact operators on $l_2$?

I can see that $V^*V$ is nothing but $M_\infty$ but I cannot see the exact claim. Please help.

Comment: Where does your notation come from?  If I translate this to the terminology I am familiar with, it seems to be asking whether or not the closed linear span of the finite-rank operators on a Hilbert space is the compact operators on the Hilbert space.  Is this what you are asking?

Comment: @Aweygan  The notation is taken from a paper by Ruan and Kaur. I know whatever you have written but how does that help? Are you saying that $V^*V= l_2$?

Comment: I'm confused by the notation $M_{1,\infty}$, what you refer to as a "row Hilbert space", and the product $x^*y$ in a Hilbert space.

Comment: If you could provide a PDF link to the paper you are reading that would help.  Otherwise, I feel like the notation is to nonstandard to allow anyone to provide specific advice to help you.

Comment: @Aweygan: "row Hilbert (operator) space" is standard operator-space terminology. Same with "column". But your intuition is exactly what it is.

Comment: @Aweygan  https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82571022.pdf Here is the link. Look at after proposition 2.1 but I just realised that the paper does not have the example but her thesis have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the row Hilbert operator space is $\{e_{1j}:\ j\in\mathbb N\}\subset B(\ell^2(\mathbb N))$, your C$^*$-algebra $W$ is generated by the matrix units $e_{kj}=e_{1k}^*e_{1j}$. So $W=K(\ell^2(\mathbb N))$, the compact operators.

Comment: Thanks. I am so dumb it was easy.